# app crashes after presenting an UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, dealloc, xcode6-beta6

I'm trying to present an **UIImagePickerController** in order to get an image from album and I'm facing a weird behavior.

If I launch the image picker in the **viewDidLoad**, it works:

```
class CaptureImageViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initPicker()
}

func initPicker() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    imageView.image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as UIImage
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController!) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

However, if I turn the **initPicker()** into a **@IBAction** and call it from a Button, after tapping it, the image picker appears but suddenly the app crashes with this error:

```
CaptureImageViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7960b1e0
```

I'm working on simulator with XCode Beta 6

Any idea?

Comment: Could you post the code with the IBAction please?

Comment: @Akaino, it's exactly the same code, but **initPicker()** into **viewDidLoad()** desappears. Also, **initPicker()** function definition becomes **@IBAction func initPicker(){...}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing a bunch of different ways with no success, I've changed the function signature and... it works!

It seems the `init` prefix confuses Swift.

I'm looking for some related topic in forums and official documentation, but I'm not getting anything.

Maybe a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the object of *UIImagePickerController* as an *Instance* level parameter instead of within the function.